# Logistic regression for risk adjustment

Tags: logistic, risk

I'm not sure to understant how you can use logistic regression to calculate risk-adjusted rate.

For example, I want to calculate an adjusted rate for acquiring C. difficile in a hospital. I have the real number of cases in the hospital, but I want to adjust for age, sex and other variables to compare with other hospital in Canada. I need to use the logistic regression to have my new rate adjusted.

I know I need to use coefficient derived from the regression to calculate the number of expected case and then do: number of true case / number of expected case * Canadian average

But how do I use coefficient to calculate the number of expected case?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Are you able to get the probability from the logistic regression? If you can't get the probability, what would you do once you had such a probability (such as if a consultant did the calculations to get the probability)?

Comment: Assuming the study has been designed properly to facilitate such inferences, the expected number of infections for someone of age $x$, sex $z$ and so on would be the estimated probability using those variables multiplied by the number of people with those variables.  The coefficients are used to obtain the probability, which is used to estimate the number of occurences

Comment: Most statistical software can calculate the estimated probability of the adverse outcome (usually coded 1, otherwise 0). This calculation uses the estimated coefficients, the observed variables, and the logistic link function. The total of these probabilities is usually used as an estimate of the number of adverse outcomes (or expected number) in a subgroup of interest. The sum of these estimated probabilities for all the observations equals the total number of observed adverse events. Let your software do the work.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/633056/why-is-cihi-recommending-that-we-multiply-the-multiplicative-error-estimate-by-t