# Why is CIHI recommending that we multiply the multiplicative error estimate by the per-capita rate?

Tags: risk, adjustment, application

I feel like this question is mostly about how to translate vague documentation into math than a statistics question *per se*, but please bear with me.

I am reading the [Canadian Institute for Health Information](https://www.cihi.ca/en)
's (CIHI) [Cardiac Care Quality Indicators: General Methodology Notes 2020](https://www.cihi.ca/sites/default/files/document/ccqi-general-methodology-notes.pdf). On page 8 they have the formula

$$\text{Risk-Adjusted Rate} \triangleq \frac{[\text{Observed Cases}]}{[\text{Expected Cases}]} [\text{Canadian average rate}].$$

The **observed cases** are defined as the

> number of observed events (or numerator cases, such as actual number of deaths)

, and the **expected cases** is defined as

> the number of expected events, adjusted for the distribution of risk factors in hospitals; coefficients are derived from regression models to obtain the expected number of cases.

The Canadian average rate is just the relative frequency of the event in Canada.

I have inferred that the (sample) ratio

$$\frac{[\text{Observed Cases}]}{[\text{Expected Cases}]}$$

is an estimate of the multiplicative error of the model used to estimate the expected number of cases. This model happens to be a [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression), although I am not sure that has any bearing on my question.

Rather, I am curious why they multiply by $[\text{Canadian average rate}]$. At a glance I had thought this might be a [conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation) but then I realized that we are not using the right probability for that. I also considered [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician), but that doesn't seem to work here either.

So my question is broadly **how is this definition motivated or justified** and specifically **why are we multiplying the multiplicative error estimate by the per-capita rate**?

---

A colleague of mine found some related resources where a similar calculation is performed.

- https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://community.jmp.com/kvoqx44227/attachments/kvoqx44227/discussions/50682/1/PAPER225.PDF&ved=2ahUKEwiYgumAy_eCAxXarokEHcWJA6YQFnoECCcQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2b3Z7RT8qVA1hkcipA4nVZ
- https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X19854021&ved=2ahUKEwiYgumAy_eCAxXarokEHcWJA6YQFnoECCEQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3oUPZSdkwWXcazhdqfGTRU

Comment: Doesn't look like [marginalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution) either.

Comment: This might be related to [post stratification](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_23/stan-users-guide/poststratification.html).

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/561814/logistic-regression-for-risk-adjustment?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be trying to answer the question "if a center had a population that had the average rate for the country, how would the center's rate of events look like". It's making the assumption that any deviation from what is expected would be proportionally the same at all risk levels and that the prediction behind the expected cases is correct (without that relating observed to expected is problematic in the first place, of course - the document mentions those limitations:"[...] risk-adjustment modelling cannot entirely eliminate differences in patient characteristics among centres because not all pre-admission influences are adjusted
for [...]").

If it's okay to compare expected vs. observed, then just looking at the ratio (e.g. 2.0 = doubled rate over what is expected, 0.5 = halved rate vs. what is expected) already gives you very similar information. However, you could argue that re-scaling it to a somewhat representative average gives you have idea of what this means in terms of absolute numbers, which could be helpful to e.g. contextualize that a 50% increase in events might be not as bad as it sounds because events are incredibly rare vs. a 5% increase in a common event might mean a much larger increase in the absolute number of events.

As the document also points out providing something like confidence intervals is also useful, because for rare events some centers must inevitably (because the event must occur somewhere...) get some imbalances (e.g. 1 observed event when 0.01 was expected = 100 $\times$ increase over what's expected), but this could very easily be chance variation which confidence intervals would highlight. You'd still have the issue that you look at lots of centers and lots of confidence intervals, you would by chance get plenty excluding 1.0 (for the ratio) or the average rate (for the re-scaled number) simply because you look at so many of them.